# compiling java springboot app in gradle container fails due to file system errors

Tags: java, docker, gradle

i have the following multistage Dockerfile

```
FROM docker.io/gradle:jdk11 as develop
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]

FROM docker.io/gradle:jdk11 as build
COPY app/ .
RUN ls
RUN gradle build

FROM gcr.io/distroless/java-debian10:11 as prd
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/project/app/build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
CMD ["/app.jar"]
```

when I get to `build` gradle blows up with filesystem errors

> Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched.
> Assuming all file systems can be watched. Reason: Could not query file
> systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or
> directory)

...

> Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched. The
> whole state of the virtual file system has been discarded. Reason:
> Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No
> such file or directory) Error: error building at STEP "RUN gradle
> build": error while running runtime: exit status 1

I want to have the `prd` image to be distroless, and done with the build command. I was trying to avoid a script, but maybe I can't.

I am asking why I'm getting this build error, and/or how to work around it?

Comment: I dont know, why you actually do a docker multi-stage build. If you already have gradle, you could build a docker image using jib plugin https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin

Comment: a couple reasons, mainly because I've never heard of jib before, so i'll take a look at that. 2, we're just starting to experiment with creating good "app" templates for our org, so ultimately multi-stage might not be a part of it.  Solving this particular problem helps with a greater understanding.  thanks for jib share @MatthiasWiedemann